# Puppeteer Getting List of Elements with Same Selector

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

**Background:**

Using NodeJS/CucumberJS/Puppeteer to build end-to-end regression test for an emberJS solution.

**Problem:**

Selecting (page.click) and getting textContent of one of the elements when there are several dynamic elements with the same selector?  (In my case, I have 4 elements with the same selector =  [data-test-foo4="true"])

I know, that with:

```
const text = await page.evaluate( () => document.querySelector('[data-test-foo4="true"]').textContent );
```

I can get the text of the first element, but how do I select the other elements with the same selector?  I've tried:

```
var text = await page.evaluate( () => document.querySelectorAll('[data-test-foo4="true"]').textContent )[1];
console.log('text = ' + text);
```

but it gives me 'text = undefined'

Also, the following:

```
await page.click('[data-test-foo4="true"]');
```

selects the first elements with that selector, but how can I select the next one with that selector?

Answer (score 50):

You can use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to create an array containing all of the [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) values of each element matching your selector:

```
const text = await page.evaluate(() => Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[data-test-foo4="true"]'), element => element.textContent));

console.log(text[0]);
console.log(text[1]);
console.log(text[2]);
```

If you need to click more than one element containing a given selector, you can create an [`ElementHandle`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-elementhandle) array using [`page.$$()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v5.5.0/docs/api.md#frameselector-1) and click each one using [`elementHandle.click()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#elementhandleclickoptions):

```
const example = await page.$$('[data-test-foo4="true"]');

await example[0].click();
await example[1].click();
await example[2].click();
```

Comment: Thanks Grant, I tried: `await page.click('[data-test-button-sort-asc-desc-toggle-type-selection="true"]');
        await page.waitFor(settings._3000);
        const text = await page.evaluate( () => Array.from( document.querySelectorAll('[data-test-button-sort-asc-desc-toggle-type-selection=="true"]' ), element => element.textContent ) );`

Comment: - but after the first part ran `page.click` successfully, I then got a`'Error: Evaluation failed: DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '[data-test-button-sort-asc-desc-toggle-type-selection=="true"]' is not a valid selector.
           at __puppeteer_evaluation_script__:1:29`

Comment: This is weird to me, usually when the selector is incorrect, I get the following error: `Error: No node found for selector: [data-test-button-sort-asc-desc-toggle-type-selection-GARBAG="true"]`

Comment: You have a double equal sign (`==`) in `querySelectorAll(...)` which is causing an error. It should be one equal sign: `=`.

Comment: Ah ha!  I put a <span><span> around the element(s) with the tag and it worked `<span data-test-foo="true">
 {{option.label}}
</span>`

Answer (score 6):

https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v5.5.0/docs/api.md#frameselector-1

```
const pageFrame = page.mainFrame();
const elems = await pageFrame.$$(selector);
```

Answer (score 3):

Not mentioned yet is the awesome `page.$$eval` which is basically a wrapper for this common pattern:

```js
page.evaluate(() => callback([...document.querySelectorAll(selector)]))
```

For example,

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^19.1.0

const html = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<ul>
  <li data-test-foo4="true">red</li>
  <li data-test-foo4="false">blue</li>
  <li data-test-foo4="true">purple</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>`;

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.setContent(html);

  const sel = '[data-test-foo4="true"]';
  const text = await page.$$eval(sel, els => els.map(e => e.textContent));
  console.log(text); // => [ 'red', 'purple' ]
  console.log(text[0]); // => 'red'
  console.log(text[1]); // => 'purple'
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

If you want to pass additional data from Node for `$$eval` to use in the browser context, you can add additional arguments:

```js
const text = await page.$$eval(
  '[data-test-foo4="true"]',
  (els, data) => els.map(e => e.textContent + data),
  "X" // 'data' passed to the callback
);
console.log(text); // => [ 'redX', 'purpleX' ]
```

You can use `page.$$eval` to issue a native DOM click on each element or on a specific element:

```js
// click all
await page.$$eval(sel, els => els.forEach(el => el.click()));

// click one (hardcoded)
await page.$$eval(sel, els => els[1].click());

// click one (passing `n` from Node)
await page.$$eval(sel, (els, n) => els[n].click(), n);
```

or use `page.$$` to return the elements back to Node to issue trusted Puppeteer clicks:

```js
const els = await page.$$('[data-test-foo4="true"]');

for (const el of els) {
  await el.click();
}

// or click the n-th:
await els[n].click();
```

Pertinent to OP's question, you can always access the n-th item of these arrays with the usual syntax `els[n]` as shown above, but often, it's best to select based on the `:nth-child` pseudoselector. This depends on how the elements are arranged in the DOM, though, so it's not as general of a solution as array access.